# Equivalence Relations Help

Tags: discrete-mathematics

> For $n,m \in \mathbb{Q}$, is $n=m, n=-m$ an equivalence relation?

This problem seems trivial as it is clearly symmetric, transitive and reflexive. Am I missing something?

Comment: If the coma in $n=m,n=-m$ means *or*, then you are not missing anything.

Comment: No, you are right, it is an equivalence relation, where each rational is related only to it's additive inverse, and itself.